# How to change Background Color of row in List View Using List View Column Field

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to change the back ground of my list view row if the column value is same the the list view back ground would be change here is my code.

```
  public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";

    List<Map<String, String>> prolist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] from = {"C", "D", "E"};
        int[] views = {R.id.accname, R.id.openingbalance, R.id.closingblanace};
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                prolist, R.layout.reportlayout, from,
                views);
        lstpro.setAdapter(ADA);


    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                final String stringlevel = getArguments().getString("level");
                String query = "select * from GLSCOADetail where AccLevelNo<='"+ stringlevel +"'";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("C", rs.getString("AccName"));
                    datanum.put("D", rs.getString("OpeningBalance"));
                    datanum.put("E", rs.getString("ClosingBalance"));

                    prolist.add(datanum);
                }

                z = "Success";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = ex.getMessage();

        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

I want to change my list view background on database filed if my database field match with list view then color of row would change please help me out.

Comment: You need therefore a custom List Adapte:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main (Activity)

```
    public class Main extends Activity
{
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    public  ListView mListView = null;
    public ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        setListData();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, CustomListViewValuesArr);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
    public void setListData()
    {
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(new ListModel("No1"));
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(new ListModel("No2"));//same
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(new ListModel("No3"));
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(new ListModel("No4"));
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(new ListModel("No2"));//same

    }

}
```

listview_layout.xml (Activity xml)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomAdapter (Adapter)

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<ListModel> mList;
    private static LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private ListModel tempValues = null;
    private int i=0;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        mActivity = a;
        mList = d;
        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        mInflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if(mList.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return mList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView text;

    }

    /****** Depends upon mList size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(mList.size() <= 0)
        {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");
        }
        else
        {
            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = ( ListModel ) mList.get( position );
            holder.text.setText( tempValues.getName() );
        }

        if(isDuplicate(tempValues.getName()))// this Method to check duplicate.
        {
            // Set a background color for ListView regular row/item
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB6B546"));
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the background color for alternate row/item
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCCB4C"));
        }
        return vi;
    }

    private boolean isDuplicate(String item)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++)
        {
            ListModel listModel = mList.get(i);
            if(item.equals(listModel.getName()))
                count++;
        }
        if(count > 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

ListModel (Model Class)

```
    public class ListModel {
    private  String name ="";

    /*********** Set Methods ******************/

    public ListModel(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String CompanyName)
    {
        this.name = CompanyName;
    }

    /*********** Get Methods ****************/

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

tabitem (ListView Adapter xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: after list added to adapter the call notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: ok but I used adapter in post execute the get view method how can i use it please send me code of list view that i add in my code wit no errors

Comment: sry try this one. if any doubt ask me.

Comment: sir can you tell me that how to check from database field if it is equal then change those rows in list view that match from the data base field